# Blank space at bottom of footer (on Mobile)

Tags: html, css, iphone

I'm trying to fix a blank space at bottom of footer (I'm seeing in iPhone 7 Plus mobile). I honestly need help with this.

I've tried various methods (ie: overflow, margin, padding) and none had worked. I also tried to view mobile version on page testing sites but they don't show any blank space.

[image]
Odd or is it just my phone?

Comment: The blank space is also visible on desktop browser

Comment: First loose the inline style attributes in your html `<div class="wsite-section wsite-body-section" style="height: auto;">` (and thereafter). As inline rules have the highest precedence they will counteract anything you wrote in your CSS.

Comment: @Gustavo What OS, what browser? On W10 FF, Chrome, IE11 it looks fine. Hold on, Edge fails...

Comment: Gretel, do not expect us to debug your site, especially without code or any [repro]. LOOSE the inline styling first (if at all possible).

Comment: There seems to be something that's causing body to add "padding-bottom: 16px !important;" whenever I scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through your code - this `img` element seems to be creating the issue:

```
<img src="https://tags.rd.linksynergy.com/cs?ns=ssc&amp;uid3=5d062c714cedfd0012d95054">
```

Oddly enough, the img element is only there when I first visit the page. If I refresh the page, the element is gone. This leads me to believe that there is some JavaScript dynamically adding it to the HTML. The image itself seems to broken and never loads either. See screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of broken img element in footer]

Comment: You are correct. I dynamically added a css code to display none on this object/element.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to remove this `<img>` added the end of the file
[image]